# Bind Radiobuttonlist using database and ajax asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, radiobuttonlist

**Web API**

```
[HttpPost]  //Get Vendor Master
    public HttpResponseMessage GetVendorMaster(dynamic inXml)
    {
        string typeids = inXml.inXml;
        int TypeID = Convert.ToInt32(typeids);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {

            Content = new StringContent(clsCommonLib.DataTableToJSON(MasterDetailsBO.GetVendorMaster(TypeID)), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
```

Data:
"[{"ID":14,"journey_Name":"One Way"},{"ID":15,"journey_Name":"Two Way"},{"ID":16,"journey_Name":"Multi City"}]"

**Ajax Method:**

```
function bind()
{

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: vUrlWithClass,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: param,
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        var result = $.parseJSON(data.d)
        console.log(data)        

            $.each(result, function (index, list) {

                    var rdb = "<tr><td><input id=rb" + this['Text'] + "  type='radio' name='rbCategories' value=" + this['Text'] + " /><label for=lbl" + this['Text'] + ">" + this['Text'] + "</label></td></tr>";
                    table.append(rdb);
                //$("#cphDashboard_ddlJourneytype").append($("<option></option>").val(list.ID).html(list.journey_Name));

            })

    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
        alert(result)
    }
});
}
}
```

**ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbJourneyTypeAir" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="FormatRadioButtonList">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

But I am unable to bind data with Radio button list

Comment: You are confusing server side and client side. RadioButtonList is server side. ASP.NET 4.0 has the ability to do client-side data binding Data Binding in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309508.aspx)


If you are not using .4.0, then it is simply a matter of iterating through your array and appending html elements to the container

Comment: Your method is prefixed with **Get** and you are making a **Post**, the nomenclature difference is confusing.. Please update to conform to design guideling

Comment: What error are you getting while binding to radio button list

Comment: unable to bind radio button list with database

Answer (score 0):

From what is evident from the sample code:-

1. The http verb (Post) and the method's name (Get...) mismatch. You need to understand when to use get vs post for a resource
2. What does `this["Text"]` evaluate to? Ideally it should be an iterator to enable dynamic ids for repeater controls. It looks like they are same for all radio buttons.
3. If 'text' evaluates to a string, make sure there's no space or special character in it which may prevent in generating a valid Id
4. Place a debugger inside the success handler to see the values of "list". You may need to expand it to identify the structure returned.

If there are any specific error reported, please update the post